# The easiest way to populate JTable from query

Tags: java, sql, jtable

```
+-------+------+------+  
|  name | level| score|  
+-------+------+------+  
|  data | data | data |  
+-------+------+------+
```

This is how I would like to show in `JTable`.

//SQL

```
static String[][] executeQuery(){  
  blabla;

  rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);  
  int i=0;  
  while(rs.next()){  
    query[0][i++] = rs.getString("name ");  
    query[1][i] = rs.getString("level");  
    query[2][i] = rs.getString("score");  
  }  
  return query;  
}  

//MAIN  
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

String[][] getScores = executeQuery();  
Object[][] data = getScores ;  
String[] columnNames = {"name ","level","score"};  

JTable table = new JTable (data, columnNames);  
table.setEnabled(false);  
panel.add(table);  

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
```

Result of this is is 3x3 table which is not properly oriented. Dont know why?
My question is: do you have some other example or do you see some errors i made ..
I have only this example but its too complicated for me - beginner:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0309.html

Comment: Can you please format that code?

Comment: What is your sql query?  You could simply query for the columns you want to populate in the table and fill it out like the example does, by calling an incremental getObject call.  Looks like the sql query would be something like "select name,level,score from mytable", depending on your table name.  Then you shouldn't have to change as much of the code in the example as you have in your code listing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the data to a DefaultTableModel. See the "Table From Database Example" code found in the [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) article.